# Solve a system of equations involving two ellipses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, systems-of-equations

[Problem #38](http://my.hrw.com/math06_07/student/pdf/english/alg2/alg2_07_0773.pdf) asks us to solve the system using either graphing, substitution, or elimination. The only way that I can think of doing this is by graphing. However, is there any easy way to solve this problem by doing elimination or substitution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use elimination on $x^2$, it becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{25} = 1 \\
\\
\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1 \\
\end{cases}
\implies
\frac{y^2}{25} - \frac{y^2}{4} = 0
$$
from which it follows that $y^2 = 0 \implies y = 0$. Thus, evaluating each equation with $y=0$ gives the solutions $(4,0)$ and $(-4, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the first terms in each equation are equal. All you have to do is subtract the first equation from the second and they will cancel, leaving:

$$ \frac{y^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{25} = 0$$

Continuing, you'll get $y^2 = 0$ and $x^2 = 16$

For the general methods, yes you can solve this using either substitution or elimination. Since $x$ and $y$ only have powers of 2, you can treat $x^2$ and $y^2$ as variables and you're back to a linear system of equations. You know how to solve that, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  let $u = x^2$, and $v = y^2$.  What type of system of equations results from expressing the given system in terms of $u$ and $v$ instead of $x$ and $y$?  Do you know how to solve this type of system?  What methods have you learned to find the solution?  Once you find the solution for the auxiliary variables $u$ and $v$, how do you then express the solution set for $x$ and $y$?  Be sure to check your solutions to see if they are in fact correct.